# Javascript getElementsByTagName() and insertAdjacentHTML()

Tags: javascript

I wonder where I did wrong because it needs to show like this.

[image]

But somehow it shows like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXEg4.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXEg4.png)

Here is my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEoC8.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEoC8.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other textual information **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Because I'm having a good eye day and can ***just*** about make out the call to `getElementsByTagName`, the problem is a syntax error (or typo): You shouldn't have the `.` before the `[0]`. If you look in your browser's devtools console, you'll see an error there. But you might consider `document.querySelector("article").insertAdjacentHTML(/*...*/);` instead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When does any part of `reviewCode` have a "P" or "N"? Especially since it's initial value is `""`

Answer (score 1):

I think function will terminate after

```
return imageText;
```